# А нельзя как-то отмечать, что правка отклонена автором вопроса/ответа?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено

Я периодически пересматриваю свои отклоненные правки и столкнулся с, на первый взгляд, [странной ситуацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/209180): 2 проверяющих приняли изменения, 1 отклонил, а правка все равно отклонена.

Да, через какое-то время я догадался сравнить ник проверяющего и автора вопроса и понял почему его мнение перевесило. Я не спорю - это логично.

Но может как-то отмечать в этом окне, что это не просто проверяющий, а сам автор, чтобы вопросов не было? Или это технически не реализуемо?

Да, я там вижу фон у ника, но это мало понятно для незнающего человека, может добавлять около ника "(автор вопроса/ответа)"?

Comment: Цвет фона голубоватый на имени как раз говорит, что это автор сообщения. Можно бы добавить хинт например. Но дублировать дополнительно текстом, я думаю, нет особого смысла. Только засорение страницы.

Comment: Я понимаю, но про это нужно знать. А сколько пользователей SO об этом знают? Если даже я при тысяче правок и ревью на  английском SO об этом не знал. И сколько догадаться сами?

Comment: К сожалению, нельзя сделать всё подряд очевидным для всех подряд. Иначе бы не было и Меты и вопросов в поддержку. Даже многореповые участники с многолетним стажем узнают что-то новое в поведении сайта. С этим ничего не поделать.

Comment: Все подряд нельзя, но сделать что-то более очевидным (если не мешает остальному) это вроде бы хорошая практика UI?

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin, нет, фона достаточно.

Answer (score 5):

Везде на сайте имя автора выделяется фоном:

В результатах проверки:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В комментариях:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Читайте вопрос до конца!

Comment: Я понимаю, но про это нужно знать. А сколько пользователей SO об этом знают? Если даже я при тысяче правок и ревью на  английском SO об этом не знал. И сколько догадаються сами?

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin не могу предположить, сколько догадаются. Я сам давно догадался и мне это уже давно кажется привычным. У вас есть идеи, как сделать понятнее, но интерфейс не усложнять?

Comment: Может быть добавить хотя бы всплывающую подсказку (хотя бы в это окно)? Либо вверху писать не "Отклонена", а "Отклонена автором"?

Comment: Черт, никогда этого не замечал! Но выделяется имя автора вопроса, даже в комментариях под ответом другого участника!

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin мне нравится ваша идея, ещё аналогично может быть «Отклонена/принята модератором». Закинете фичереквест на Мету SE?

Comment: Напишу, на выходных, сейчас нет времени