# Здесь предпочтение отдаём словам на русском языке или, превозмогая трудности, используем иностранные слова, написанные русскими буквами?

Tags: обсуждение, правки, откат-правок

Читая некоторые вопросы, ответы и прочие сообщения, в которых используются такого рода извращённые слова, такие как "хинты", "шаринг", "футер" и тому подобные, невольно рука тянется за... точнее к ссылке "править". Что я зачастую и делаю везде, где только возможно, в тех случаях, когда можно однозначно выразить описываемую сущность русскими словами. Это и было сделано недавно в следующих вопросах:

- [Нехватка переводов в новом хинте строки поиска](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9481)
- [Не переведены строки в новом окне шаринга](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9499/)
- [После смены лицензии пропал перевод в футере сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9483/)

Однако вопрошающим, имеющим к тому же ромб возле имени, эти правки были отменены. Вступать же в пререкания и обсуждения в каждом таком случае не представляется возможным, так как является пустой тратой времени. В связи с этим хотелось бы прояснить правила игры в данном сообществе по поводу высказывания своих мыслей с использованием иностранных слов, написанных русскими буквами без перевода как такового, и способов по устранению данного захламления русского сообщения.

### Дополнение

Есть схожий вопрос [IT-"жаргон", околокомпьютерный диалект](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2903/213987), но отличие моего вопроса от него заключается в прояснении правил по поводу правок, связанных с заменой иностранных "переводов" на понятные русскоязычным читателям слова.

Comment: @AK нет, это не совсем то. Мой вопрос не про хорошо/плохо, а про можно/нельзя, хотя бы на примере тех правок, что я привёл в качестве примера.

Comment: Автор вопроса имеет [некоторые преимущества в голосовании](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6292/213987), тут не нужно никакого ромба. Во всех трёх случаях не было никакого голосования, т.к. ваш лимит репутации позволяет вам делать внесение правок в обход очереди. Фактически, топикстартер воспользовался механизмом отката и очень похвально, что вы оба не стали устраивать войны правок (вам нужны сслыки на мета-топики о войнах правок?) Ещё по теме: [Почему авторы отклоняют правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5309/213987) -- как правило это а) мелкость б) противоречат замыслу автора.

Comment: "Подъезжая к сией станцыи и глядя на природу в окно, у меня слетела шляпа."

Comment: Лично я уже не отличаю английские слова на русском в тексте от обычных слов.

Comment: @AntonSorokin это поправимо.

Comment: Больше всего мне нравится заголовок этого топика. "Хотите жить в цветущей Америке или предпочитаете превозмогая трудности влачить существование в загнивающей России?"

Comment: @АндрейNOP это что-то со зрением. Суть немного не про это)

Comment: давайте уточним. То есть вы своими правками не делаете вопрос понятней, не делаете его лучше, не добавляете в него ничего по сути, вы только меняете одни всем понятные слова на другие, которые больше подхдят по вашему мнению? В чем ценность такой правки для автора вопроса? Автора ответа? Сообщества?

Comment: @tym32167 читали ответ Николая?

Comment: Николай дал такой ответ, которым можно крутить и трактовать как хочешь, потому я и задал вам вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167 https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51890349#51890349 вот его пояснение. Там всё предельно разжёвано.

Comment: "Превозмогая трудности" из заголовка вопроса я бы выпилил конечно, это искажает суть. Вопрос касается только людей у которых трудности с написанием иностранных слов русскими буквами? Людям которым не трудно писать транслитом - стоит продолжать писать транслитом?

Comment: прочитал, очередная драма и срач, вопросов к вам больше не имею.

Comment: @yolosora исправьте, как считаете нужным, если будет искажён смысл откатим.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо.

Comment: @edem я довольно косноязычный, но думаю что-то в духе "
Какие версии терминов использовать: русскоязычные или кальку с англоязычных? По каким критериям делать выбор?" возможно нужен некий перефраз основный на "Как выбрать вариант написания термина"

Comment: @yolosora нет, это немного про другое будет. Здесь вопрос про предпочтения, принятые руководством, в первую очередь. С донесением этой мысли пока есть некоторые сложности.

Comment: Вопросы на мете по большей части воспринимаются как вопросы для обсуждения с сообществом, если интересует именно мнение администрации, то я бы добавил "Какова позиция администрации по вопросу X". Однако если подразумевалось это, то вопрос уже уехал не в ту степь и менять поздно)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> #### Коротко
>
> #### Это сайт на русском языке. Чем «чище» будет ваш русский, тем лучше.

Как–то мне посчастливилось побывать на конференции в Саратове, где выступал русскоязычный докладчик, который давно проживает в Штатах. В речи докладчика было очень много англицизмов. Средний отзыв о докладе в соц. сетях был примерно такой: «Каждое второе слово режет ухо. Докладчик на русском говорит, вообще, или на английском?»

Примерно об этом же говорится в вопросе «[Зачем нужен Stack Overflow на русском?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/173/6)»: чем чище ваш русский, тем выше скорость прочтения и глубина понимания текста. Заимствованные слова зачастую не вызывают тех эмоций (а вместе с ними нужных ассоциаций, синонимов) и, как результат, полноты картины, чем понятные нам с детства слова («эксекютнуть бинарь» или «запустить программу»?) Начинающему разработчику будет куда проще разобраться в проблеме, если решение описано знакомыми ему словами без жаргонизмов («чтобы проджект не фейлелся при билде» или «чтобы сборка проекта завершилось без ошибок»?)

Для правок в общем существует универсальный подход. Если вы размышляете о том, стоит ли вносить правку, задайте себе вопрос «*Сделает ли моя правка содержимое сайта лучше для сообщества: понятнее, более легким к восприятию, приятнее к прочтению и т.д.?*» Если ответ «да» - смело вносите правку. На мой взгляд, в случае с англицизмами, в подавляющем большинстве случаев, ответ будет «да».

К слову, если посмотреть на первые несколько тысяч вопросов на сайте, то можно увидеть огромное количество правок — мы с первого дня уделяли невероятное внимание тому, чтобы вопросы были написаны понятно, в том числе мы заменяли англицизмы (в какой–то момент даже наняли редактора для этих целей). Невероятно здорово, что сегодня улучшением качества содержимого занимаются и другие неравнодушные участники.

---

Уверен, любой из нас может вспомнить куда более странные фразы, по сути, написанные транслитом, которые к русскому языку можно отнести лишь из-за использования кириллицы. Если у вас есть примеры, пожалуйста, напишите их в комментариях к этому вопросу.

Comment: очень явно и хорошо описано почему, _биг дата, видиоблогинг_ и остальное _рейп ин еёр асс_ . Не очень хорошо как для говорящей так и для слушающей  персоны. **Очень понравился ваш ответ и прекрасное изложение**

Comment: @timob256 ну-ка предложи тогда русскоязычный аналог слову видеоблогинг. Еще бы и слово персона не использовать, а то это же латынь.

Comment: Известный физик Лео Сцилард читал свой первый доклад на английском языке. После доклада к нему подошел физик Джексон и спросил:

"– Послушайте, Сцилард, на каком, собственно, языке вы делали доклад?"

Сцилард смутился, но тут же нашелся и ответил:

"– Разумеется, на венгерском, разве вы этого не поняли?"

"– Конечно, понял. Но зачем же вы натолкали в него столько английских слов?" – отпарировал Джексон.

Comment: @yolosora Так можно до мычания и жестов спуститься (а потом окажется, что и их кто–то у кого–то заимствовал). Речь конечно же идет о словах, у которых уже есть удачные эквиваленты на русском языке, например, билдить == собирать, бага == ошибка, фиксить == исправлять и т.д.

Comment: @yolosora русскоязычный аналог слова _видеоблогинг_  == _видеодневник_ ._видеоблогер_ == _видиодневниковед_. Слово в предложении : вчера смотрел кино одного видеодневниковеда , мне очень понравилось что он сказал. Конечно можно использовать американизмы _ле 56% файсе_,  _но хомо хоуми_ ,_препере ёу анусе_ , но увы я не учился в [ВШЭ](https://www.hse.ru/) и не знаю таких "ловких" наречий. Извини что плохо разбираюсь в латыне ;_; можешь пожалуйста перевести с латыни фразу (возможно она на американском , прост я весьма плох и в том и другом ;_;) _стоп бе гуд гой плиз_

Comment: @timob256 видео - тоже не русское слово, я к этому

Comment: @yolosora так удалось перевести фразу ? я к этому.

Comment: @yolosora "видео" - это русское слово, просто заимствованное, вместе с понятием, которое оно обозначает. "видеоблоггинг" - это английское слово, записанное русскими буквами. Я не имею ничего против "видеоблог" ("видеодневник" кажется плохой заменой, это не одно и то же), но суффикса "инг" в русском нет.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight video — я вижу; audio — я слышу. Это в переводе с латыни. Это вообще глагол.

Comment: @timob256 могли бы написать что лучше не гуглить ваши фразы на английском :/

Comment: @AntonSorokin вот, наглядная польза от того, почему эти "слова" на английском, написанные русскими буквами, нужно уметь отличать "от обычных слов")

Comment: @edem тут проблема в том что некоторые слова мне неизвестны. Например, я загуглил фразу т.к. не понял что значит `рейп`. Тут это был утрированный пример, в обычной же жизни используются только общеизвестные слова.

Comment: @AntonSorokin ох уж эта "необычная жизнь" на ruSO)

Comment: @timob256 blog - это we*b log*, так что должно получится "видеосетеденевниковод"

Comment: Этот ответ — очередной пример того, что галочки на мете бессмысленны.

Comment: @timob256 я прочитал ваше предложение со словом «видеодневниковед». Оно отвратительно звучит. Хорошо, что есть нормальное русское слово «блогер».

Answer (score 14):

Раз уже этот вопрос возник после моих откатов (не тех откатов (¬‿¬ )), выскажусь.

> используются такого рода извращённые слова

Не все считают подобное "извращением".

> Однако вопрошающим, имеющим к тому же ромб возле имени, эти правки были отменены.

Я такие правки в своих сообщениях откатывал ещё до ромба. Эти вещи никак не связаны, это моя позиция как участника сообщества.

---

Можно почитать вот этот тред для начала: [Прекратите редактировать мои «хрен» и «фиг»! >:(](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7140/15479).

Плюс, ещё были обсуждения на эту тему.

Я откатываю правки в своих сообщениях, т.к. они, по моему мнению, никак не улучшают сообщения. Используемые мной англоизицизмы понятны, даже больше, они постоянно используются при общении, что в сети, что irl. Если хочется побороться за чистоту русского языка, то можно это сделать, например, на [РЯ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/).

Хуже всего в этом всём для меня, как автора, это то, что по вот таким вмешательствам в мои сообщения я не получаю уведомлений. Было недавно обсуждение: [Почему при редактировании вопроса или ответа к автору не приходит уведомление?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9500/15479) Хотя предпосылки там были другие.

Меня очень печалит направление на выпиливание личностной и эмоциональной составляющей с ресурса. Хоть это и "база знаний", не нужно делать из ресурса сухой набор вопросов-ответов, т.к, в первую очередь, важны люди.

Comment: 1. Кто не считает, тех правим. 2. Про ромб упомянул к слову, я знаю как работают правки здесь. 3. На Мета давно и обсуждения по поводу русского языка мне известны, кроме "официального" взгляда на этот вопрос. 4. Мне, например, непонятны, в частности ваш "хинт" и "шаринг" (напоминает созвучное наименование с корнем сахар, к слову). 5. По-русски говорят не только на РЯ, там, кстати, этого "добра" также хватает. 6. Про "сухость" сообщений не было и речи, это уже немного другой вопрос.

Comment: 1. Вероятно после ответов в этом вопросе, вам придётся изменение позицию. 2) Не уверен. Про англоицизмы в справке ни слова. Впрочем, прошлые обсуждения тоже неоднозначны оказались по итогу в этом плане. 5) Откуда такой уничижительный тон?

Comment: 1. Что не запрещено, знаете ли... 2. Я про способ, а не про повод. 5. Это всё личностная составляющая сообщения).

Comment: Очень важное, на мой взгляд, замечание: вопрос про «хрен и фиг» о комментариях, а не вопросах и ответах. На сколько помню, там фишка в том, что не очевидно, как посмотреть, что есть правка, что есть авторское сообщение, плюс сами комментарии не относятся к базе знаний. Вообще, запрещать кому–то что–то улучшать в сообщении — странно. Правка на то и была добавлена, чтобы сообщения со временем становились только лучше, в том числе за счет повышения читабельности.

Comment: С другой стороны, конечно, много англицизмов давно закрепились в нашей культуре. Ничего в этом плохого нет. Просто если есть возможность описать явление более понятным языком, так и стоит поступить. (П.С. На «irl» на несколько десятков секунд.)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky изменение на русскоязычный аналог не всегда приводит к улучшению читабельности. Стоит также обратить внимание на огромнейший пласт слов, заимствованных из иностранных языков. Почему то, что заимствовалось когда-то в прошлом мы считаем правильным и естественным, а новых заимствований боимся? Главное везде придерживаться здравого смысла.

Comment: @yolosora «_не всегда приводит к улучшению читабельности_» — на мой взгляд, крайне редко. Кстати, приведите, пожалуйста, такие примеры? В остальном согласен. Главное — здравый смысл и чтобы понятно было =)

Comment: @yolosora мы это кто?

Comment: @edem я смотрю, вам плевать на просьбы других не править их сообщения. Что ж, я вас услышал.

Comment: @Suvitruf ух, что-то интересное намечается

Comment: @AntonSorokin да нет, всё уже закончилось. Я к локализации и т.п. больше не притронусь, пускай адепты русского языка этим занимаются, а то я опять эту "деградацию" и "варваризм" принесу, люди страдать будут.

Comment: @Suvitruf все это печально видеть. К сожалению, все больше и больше "старичков" отдаляются от сайта. Лично я вообще удивлен, как вы(все активные участники) продолжаете тратить(не в негативном смысле, скорее "проводить") столько своего времени на сайт.

Comment: @Suvitruf пока я не вижу новых участников(новые хорошие отвечающие - да, новые люди активно принимающие участие в жизни сайта - нет). Не знаю, почему.

Comment: @AntonSorokin я тут сижу, т.к. мне приятно помогать другим, даже несмотря на ненависть и неприязнь со стороны некоторых участников.

Comment: @Suvitruf а может быть, наоборот, кому-то плевать на просьбы других не портить язык?

Comment: @Suvitruf благодарю за столь мудрое решение отойти от дел, касательно переводов.

Comment: @edem а кто будет заниматься локализацией? Может быть вы?

Comment: @AntonSorokin ой ой ой, он был единственным человеком, кто занимался переводами?!

Comment: @edem нет, но его посты на мете я видел очень часто

Comment: @AntonSorokin мы точно о переводах говорим? Потому что последние примеры, которые мне довелось увидеть от этого человека, было скорее обычной заменой букв одной абэшки на другую. hint — хинт, sharing — шаринг. Это не перевод.

Comment: @edem Антон говорит про перевод интерфейса сайта, а вы про то, что вам не нравится текст в моих сообщениях. Вы абсолютно про разные вещи пишите.

Comment: Если вы применяете такой же подход для перевода на ruSO, то суть от этого не меняется.

Comment: @edem опять эти "если". Своим глазам уже не доверяете?

Comment: @Suvitruf вы меня не перестаёте удивлять, т.е. некоторые обладатели ромба, помимо чтения мыслей, умеют ещё и взглядом на слово ruSO сказать, кто его перевёл?.. Круто! Нет слов.

Comment: @edem это же вы про какие-то "если" пишете. Сайту много лет, интерфейс мы переводим много лет. Если вы про его "плохую" локализацию ничего не пишете, то тут два вариант: либо всё хорошо и тогда вы просто троллите, либо плохо, но тогда не понятно, почему вы раньше никогда про это не писали.

Answer (score 11):

Мы работаем в такой сфере, где заимствование технологий приближается к 95%. Конечно слова, термины, концепции тоже заимствуются. Это неизбежно. Язык живет и развивается.

Как быть? Относиться толерантнее, и править только самые вопиющие случаи <s>мисъюза вордов и терминолоджи</s> кривого использования слов и терминологии.

Comment: Развитие, в отличии от расхлябанности, подразумевает ограничение, и это вам подтвердит любой представитель из любой области деятельности, достигший успехов чуть выше, чем средних, в нашей в том числе. Язык в этом случае не исключение, поэтому давайте хотя бы не называть это "развитием", раз уж на поддержание порядка сил не хватает.

Comment: @edem Мы живём в эпоху, когда русский язык бурно развивается из-за соприкосновения с другими культурами, да -- в том числе и за счёт заимствований. Я много общаюсь с филологами и языковедами и AFAIK среди них такое явление считается вполне нормальным. В языке  настолько большое число слов, которые были заимствованы относительно давно по историческим меркам, но к которым все привыкли и не воспринимают как чужеродные слова. Есть некоторая разумная середина между ханжеством/пуританством и небрежным отношением к родному языку -- для себя решил, что стоит придерживаться её и не обвинять других.

Comment: Здесь речь идет не о любых заимствованиях (это было бы абсурдным, так как число заимствований в русском языке фантастически велико - навскидку, даже слово "телега" является вроде заимствованным из монгольского). "Хинт" - это варваризм, заимствование, которое еще не вошло в общеупотребительную речь. Употребление таких слов вполне может считаться ненормальным, но я согласен с призывом "Относиться толерантнее". Не все, что не нормально, нужно править.

Comment: @AK речь была про обвинения разве? Я думал, что я спрашиваю про можно/нельзя править, а оно вон что...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вы правы, речь про большинство англоязычных слов, пришедших к нам из-за океана, как правило.

Comment: @edem У меня подходил лимит символов в комментарии, поэтому мысль немного скомкана. Да, в моём личном опыте как-то преимущественно темы языкового пуританства имеют тенденцию скатываться в неприглядные ссоры, взаимообвинения и т.п. И нет, я не имел ввиду конкретно вас, если вы об этом. Не было у меня таких интенций, если где-то увидели -- покажите, я поправлю/уберу. Мысль которую я не развернул была такова: все люди разные и стандарты у всех разные.

Comment: @AK нет, не про меня, лишь уточнил про суть вопроса, что он не про обвинения.

Comment: @AK да, вы правы, только вот язык, принятый для общения в этом месте, один.

Comment: @edem Если только англоязычных, это неполиткорректно :) Могут быть и из других языков, например "граммарнаци" - варваризм из немецкого.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight если присмотреться, то там не было слова "только" ;)

Comment: Эти заявления про "развитие" языка меня уже начинают злить. Язык не развивается, а деградирует.

Comment: Эти заявления про "деградацию" языка меня уже начинают злить. Язык не деградирует, а развивается.

Comment: @Kromster подмена понятий, Igor прав)

Comment: @edem подмена понятий, Kromster прав)

Comment: @Suvitruf в чём?

Comment: @edem в том что это субъективное мнение. Я вот написал свое, аналогичное

Comment: Эти заявления про "деградацию/развитие" языка меня уже начинают злить. Язык не деградирует и не развивается, а эволюционирует.

Comment: Видел отзыв на переводную книгу - дословно не помню, но примерно *"ваш переводчик ничего не понимает в терминологии - например, зачем говорить "связать", когда есть давно устоявшийся термин "прибиндить"?"* Всегда вспоминается тот анекдот (который ныне не анекдот) про украинскую семью в Канаде - "Джоне, зашатай дуру, бо чилдренятка покулднуть"...

Comment: Что развитие, что эволюция могут быть как и положительными, так и отрицательными. Вероятно, правильное противопоставление - это "деградация/усовершенствование". Лично я не вижу, как механический перенос англицизмов в русский язык можно считать усовершенствованием, тем более на сайте, весь смысл которого (с точки зрения его основателей, по крайней мере) - сделать знания доступными как раз для тех, кто *не знает* английский. Вводить на основе иностранных свои термины для новых понятий, с которыми язык раньше не сталкивался - безусловно, усовершенствование. Но в данном случае этого не было.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight проблема в том, что оценка "положительности" или "отрицательности" субъективна. Не бывает "отрицательной эволюции" по самому определению эволюции. Эволюция означает, что язык стал более приспособленным. Английский, например, стал гораздо более простым после его глобального распространения. Наверняка кто-то заявлял при этом, что язык деградировал"

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Даже в случае русского языка, и в случае IT можно найти удачные примеры замены существующих терминов просто по незнанию - за последние 30 лет термины операция/операнд/оператор явно поменяли свой смысл. Мы используем [tag:перегрузка-операторов], хотя еще 20-30 лет назад слово operator переводили как "операция" (а statement - как "оператор"). Я лично видел, как переводчики книг боролись с "деградацией", но в конце концов сдались.

Answer (score 7):

Мы определенно, в целом, "отдаем предпочтение словам на русском языке". В интерфейсе сайта, в справке, в общих сообщениях с меткой [faq](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) варваризмам не место - если видите их там, исправьте или создайте предложение на мете. Но, когда идет речь о сообщениях конкретных участников, все становится не так просто.

Во-первых, у нас не википедия, где каждое сообщение не имеет автора и каждый может вносить правки как ему вздумается. Несмотря на часто повторяемое в том числе и модераторами (неверное) утверждение, что "сообщения авторам не принадлежат", на самом деле, конечно, принадлежат. Другие участники могут вносить правки только в соответствии со списком причин, изложенных [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing). Подпадает ли исправление варваризмов под этот список? Это спорный вопрос, но я склоняюсь к тому, что нет: это вопрос стиля, а не жесткая языковая норма. Тем более у нас даже нет официального руководства по стилю, чтобы подвести основание под такие правки. В каком стиле мы пишем на сайте? В научном варваризмы недопустимы, а в разговором или публицистическом все не так однозначно.

Во-вторых, мета - это скорее площадка для обсуждений, а не база знаний, по крайней мере должна быть таковой. Вопрос на мете (кроме FAQ) можно сравнить с темой на форуме или страницей обсуждений на википедии, а не со статьей. Лезть с правками в чужие сообщения в обсуждениях обычно не принято, даже если это касается исправления ошибок.

Наконец, смысл сайта, я полагаю, не в том, чтобы учить людей "чистому" русскому языку, а том, чтобы быть понятным широкой аудитории. Если кто-то не может обойтись без варваризмов и не понимает аналогичные русскоязычные термины, нет смысла кормить их с ложки этими терминами; это приведет только к лишнему конфликту. Борьба за чистоту языка важна, но ее нужно вести личным примером, а не насильственно. Например, если участник пишет в вопросе что-то вроде

> Какой хидер нужно подключить, чтобы использовать system("PAUSE")?

Пишем в ответе что-то вроде

> Чтобы использовать system("PAUSE"), необходимо подключить "хидер" (правильно - заголовочный файл) cstdlib

Варваризм берем в кавычки, чтобы явно дать понять, что это неправильно, и приводим в скобках правильный термин. Конечно, иногда можно попробовать и внести правки, если в сообщении есть еще что улучшить кроме этого. Но если автор хоть раз дал понять, что он против - больше не трогать стиль в его сообщениях.

Comment: "Если вам не нравится то, что ваш вклад в сообщество может редактироваться другими пользователями, возможно, вам нужен другой сайт." к слову по поводу "Но если автор хоть раз дал понять, что он против - больше не трогать стиль в его сообщениях.".

Comment: Насчёт лезть в правки в чужие сообщения (не только на мете) вполне нормальная практика. Тихо-молча поправить опечатки, если на глаза попалось -- этим многие занимаются. Общественное недовольство это вызывает в случаях, когда это часто делает участник, не набравший 2к+ репутации -- так как отвлекает сразу несколько участников на ревью, такому могут как рекомендовать не делать так до набора 2к+ либо начать методично отклонять правки как несущественные. В остальном с постом согласен, особенно с "вести личным примером".

Comment: @AK "Лезть с правками в чужие сообщения в обсуждениях обычно не принято" - я здесь в основном ссылался на правило Википедии избегать правок на страницах обсуждений. Я знаю, что у нас такого нет.

Comment: Отличный пример про «хидер»!

Answer (score -8):

## Причины, по которым такие слова появляются в нашем обиходе

- Лень.
- Скорость набора: лень переключить раскладку, давая таким образом право на жизнь такого вида языковым превращениям на письме.
- Отсутствие под рукой подходящего "перевода" для вновь появившихся на свет слов из-за границы. Там то они слова не с ходу придумывают, а тут нужно перевести здесь и сейчас. Быстро же это зачастую не прокатывает, ибо нужно прежде всего понимание того, что именуется тем или иным словом там у них. Обращаю ваше внимание, что порой перевод не всегда должен быть буквальным: слова прежде всего должны передавать смысл явления. Например, мы же не будем переводить английское mother-in-law, как "мать в законе", а переведём на русский как "тёща" или "свекровь", в зависимости от смысла сказанного.
- Недостаточное распространение слов-замен и осведомлённость о них для уже внедрившихся заимствованных слов. См. ниже, одно из решений — словарь на Meta.
- Личные предпочтения, связанные с выбором слов из русского и иностранных языков.
- Личный пример общественно значимых лиц.
- Распространённость среди иностранных товаров, разработок, устройств и описаний оных изделий. Не каждый продавец (поставщик) может достоверно объяснить суть продаваемого изделия, дабы должным образом придумать ему название на русском языке.

## Где могут встречаться подобного рода слова на ruSO

- Непосредственно на составляющих ruSO и Meta: справка, надписи, ссылки, подсказки и т.п.
- В вопросах и ответах пользователей.
- В комментариях пользователей.
- В сообщениях из беседок.
- В названиях меток.
- В описаниях меток.

## Где именно могут быть исправления

Здесь, пользователей можно разделить на два вида: собственно пользователи и руководство. Для пользователей правки ограничиваются лишь теми сообщениями, для которых предусмотрена возможность их изменения, а именно: вопросы, ответы, метки и их описание. У руководства, конечно же, возможностей по изменению больше, в том числе и по охвату доступных для правок сообщений.

Подробнее в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

## Предпринимаемые меры на ruSO

- 4 года назад для решения данного вопроса был придуман [словарь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267) технических слов, где можно найти перевод того или иного новодела, а также добавить свои предложения для последующего использования.
- Пользовательские правки вопросов и ответов.
- Деятельное использование должных слов в своих вопросах и ответах.
- Разъяснительные беседы с участниками сообщества о пользе оного подхода в рамках вопросов-ответов или в [беседке](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462).

Comment: Это достойное резюме природы человека. Вывод -- такие слова неистребимы. Интересно, а сколько в русском языке вообще не заимствованных  слов (начиная с греческих, монгольских и тюркских) (а также, очевидно финно-угорские слова какими будем считать?)

Comment: @avp Если достойное, так проголосуйте, чего же вы?)

Comment: @avp "Вывод -- такие слова неистребимы.", правильно, как и зубы на всю жизнь не начистить)

Comment: 2-4 неплохие **комментарии** по теме. Первый и последние 3 пункта .. жаль, если вы действительно так считаете. По теме вопроса - в чем именно состоит ваш ответ? Сейчас он производит впечатление "есть пара причин, но на самом деле все ленивые языконенавистники и это все насажденное". Т.е. конструктива и ответа в ответе и не видно..

Comment: @Kromster он пополняемый.

Comment: @Kromster эм, если вы ещё и влияние Петра I-го в этом вопросе начнёте отрицать, то лучше даже не начинайте)

Comment: @edem какое отношение это список "причин" имеет к вашему вопросу? Вы задали вопрос на мете, если вы даете на него ответ - то в ответе должен содержаться ответ, извините за тавтологию. Ответ - это конкретное предлагаемое вами решение, за которое смогут проголосвать другие участники. А "я думаю, что у людей неприязнь к русскому языку" - это не ответ, это просто высказываение ваших предположений относительно других участников.

Comment: @PashaPash одно из решений придумано уже задолго до меня, я на него скинул ссылку. В чём вопрос?

Comment: Поднятый вопрос рассматривается Николаем уже не первый год, к слову.

Comment: @edem если у вашего вопроса уже есть решение - его стоит закрыть как дубликат. все остальное содержание вашего "ответа" ответом не является.

Comment: @PashaPash нет, решений много, одно из них я привёл, остальные добавляю по ходу дела, за несколько лет было много придумано, но недостаточно.

Comment: @PashaPash зачем закрывать? У людей до сих пор нет осознания как здесь это работает, несмотря на "официальные" пояснения от Николая. Мой вопрос как раз про это.

Comment: @edem вот когда добавите и, заодно, уберете из ответа все, что не имеет отношения к вопросу - тогда он станет соответствовать требованиям. А пока - это набор домыслов на грани оскорблений + ссылка на другой ответ.

Comment: @edem если у вас есть вопросы к Николаю по поводу его ответа - задайте их в комментариях к его ответу.

Comment: @PashaPash вступление необходимая часть ответа.

Comment: @PashaPash что именно вас там задело?

Comment: @edem да. в случае есть при этом есть остальная часть ответа, чуть более подробная, чем ссылка на другой ответ. Ответ, состоящий исключительно из вступления - это не ответ

Comment: @edem пункты 4-7. и, возможно, слово извращение. Это мета, пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы и ответы нейтрально, так, чтобы в них не было ничего, что могло бы быть воспринято как оскорбления. формулировка "вы используете транслитерацию, наверное, вы испытываете неприязнь к русскому языку" как-то совсем на грани CoC.

Comment: @edem пожалуйста, не переходите на личности.

Comment: @PashaPash нет, это список причин, как любой список причин, причин может быть одна, а может быть более одной.

Comment: @PashaPash хорошо, только не навязывайте своё понимание ответа остальным. Ответ — ссылка, всем известно как выглядит.

Comment: Хотел бы попросить вас поправить сообщение и убрать уничижительный тон. "слова" в кавычках. "просачиваются". Это всё отдаёт очень большим негативом. Если вам заимствованные слова не нравятся, это не делает их плохими. И не даёт вам право принижать эти слова и людей, эти слова использующие.

Comment: "Просачиваются" в смысле скорости, "слова" в кавычках, в смысле, что это *произношение* и/или *написание* иностранных слов, написанное русскими буквами. На этом и заостряется внимание.

Comment: @edem не я один в подобных оборотах вижу пренебрежительный тон. Тревоги и от других пользователей поступали. Мы не можем не реагировать на это. Поэтому и рекомендую вам самим поправить сообщение.

Comment: @Suvitruf проверьте.

Comment: @edem благодарю, уже лучше)

Comment: @Suvitruf да не за что, тем более ничего особо не изменилось, что так -8 что эдак :'-(